# How can I add an unremovable suffix to an HTML input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

Using jQuery, how can I add a default suffix of `, Demos` into an input field that can’t be removed, and that still allows you to type a content before suffix?

Default: ,Demos
Content: myText, Demos

Any help would be precious!

Comment: why not add the suffix on change event?

Comment: If the suffix can't change why is in the input in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that adds a suffix on change of an input field using Jquery:

```
$('#input').on('change focus unfocus', function(){
 var inputValue = $(this).val();
 var suffix = ", Demos";
 if(!(inputValue.indexOf(suffix) > -1)){
    var newVal = inputValue + suffix;
    $(this).val(newVal);
 }else{
 var suffixLength = inputValue.indexOf(suffix) + suffix.length;
 var len = inputValue.length - suffixLength;  
 if(len >0){ 
    $(this).val((inputValue.slice(suffixLength, inputValue.lenght))+suffix);
 }
 }
```

});

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2gbs6f9/2/)

You might have to consider what you want to do if a change is made after the suffix already is applied, either delete everything or keep everything but remove all the chars after the suffix.
Also you might want to use a validation pattern to check if the suffix is applied.

**EDIT:** JSFIddle and code are updated to make the suffix pretty much unremovable.